# How to print a wider comment pane for MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-word-2007

I have a `MS Word 2007` document with some fairly lengthy comment balloons and have adjusted the preferred width of the balloons to 4" (after consulting this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1072353/how-to-change-width-of-comment-area-in-microsoft-word-2011-for-mac?newreg=dec2d30d330f4073a0c0656ea4118bd2)). The section margins are 1" (L/R) and .3" (T/B). This works well, and none of the comment text gets relegated to the end of the document this way.

However, attempts to print result in a return to the default balloon width, which sends much of the text to the end of the document. Is it possible to print a wider comment pane?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but if the goal is simply to have a printed document with the margins and balloon sizes mentioned in the question, then in `MS Word 2007`:

1. Ensure that Tracking > Final Showing Markup is selected.
2. From the Windows drop-down menu in the upper left, select Send > Email as PDF attachment.

This should produce a PDF that has the desired comment pane size and margins, although it may be scaled down somewhat.